# MongoDB - Find and update an array object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to update an object but I´m getting problems to update it.  Please check the scheme:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  teachers: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      information: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'info',
      }],
    },
  ],
```

I need to  update an information inside this scheme Im trying to do (created is the object created):

```
const person = await ctx.models.person
    .findOneAndUpdate({
      teachers: {
        $elemMatch: {
          teachers: {
            _id: input.processId,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $push: {
        teachers: {
          information: created,
        },
      },
    }, {
      new: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as recommended [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) by MongoDb official docs, you don't need $elemMatch:

> If you specify only a single  condition in the $elemMatch expression, you do not need to use $elemMatch.

Besides that, I recommend use the dot notation to search. Your code will be like that:

```
const person = await ctx.models.person
    .findOneAndUpdate({
      "teachers._id" : input.processId
    },
    {
      $push: {
        teachers: {
          information: created,
        },
      },
    }, {
      new: true,
    });
```